# Laravel Nova reducting Select options or injecting clauses to query

Tags: laravel-nova

I have an Organisation model and a Contract model

Here it is

```
class Contract extends Model {

    public function organisation() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Organisation::class, 'organisation_id', 'id')->where('is_self',1);
    }

}
```

How can I make Laravel Nova see only organisations which are is_self=1 in BelongsTo Field. Is there functionality to inject clauses to query, which forms select here?

That's how I call BelongsTo

```
BelongsTo::make('Organisation', 'organisation', Organisation::class)
    ->rules('required', 'exists:organisations,id'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make use of „Relatable Filtering“: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/authorization.html#relatable-filtering.

Comment: As I see, this will filter all relations with model, for my example Organisation. 
But in this exact form I need to use relations twice, first to filter is_self==1, the other one to filter is_self !=1
Or I am mistaken and i can specify in what case the exact method shoul be used?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. I thought you only wanted to have organisations that have your `is_self` attribute with the value `1` in the BelongsTo. Can you elaborate? Where do you need the other form respectively the `-1`?

Comment: Nevertheless, maybe my second answer will help you out.

Comment: For example my contract have 2 sides, the customer and the seller, they both are organisations, buh the seller is one of our organisations and has flag "is_self == 1", buh the customer is an Organisation too, but with "is_self != 1". The Contract CRUD form has to specify both customer and seller. That's the case

Answer (score 0):

You also don't need to stick to the `BelongsTo` field. Maybe a `Select` field fits your case?

```php
Select::make('is_self', 'organisation_id')
    ->options(function() {
        Organisation::whereIsSelf(1)->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
    })
```

This code is untested, but I'm using similar selects in my Nova apps without problems.

Comment: Thx, select works fine, but I was looking for more cute way. Added as feature request on github, but thx for help